# Is there a way to implement this layout with Jetpack compose + Material3

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-design, bottom-sheet

I want to implement this layout with images using Jetpack Compose and Material UI 3.
I tried with `ModalBottomSheet` and `BottomSheetScaffold` composables, but I also need the bottom sheet to overlap the image above like in this screenshot.

[image]

Could anyone help me with this layout and provide me with some code examples?

Comment: this can be done using ```BackdropScaffold``` but it is available only in material2 for now.

Comment: Is the white space a bottom sheet or it is a static UI?